# I am unable to get "configure webhook " option within google chat

Tags: google-chat, google-chat-api

As per the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/webhooks) it lies inside chat room option. But its not available there.

[image: Instead i am getting below options only...]

Comment: Do you have a workspace account or is it a gmail.com one when you try to configure the webhook?

Comment: I have a personal gmail.com account, i guess "Enable webhook" option will only be enabled when i have a workspace account. So, i will create one then make this work ...thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

Enable Webhook, the option can only be visible if you have a google workspace account. It's not available on the personnel's Gmail account.

Answer (score 2):

The **Configure webhook** option is indeed available only for Workspace users so you will have to use a Workspace account in order to set it up.

As for the documentation, I have taken the opportunity to file [this report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193885860) in order to improve the documentation regarding this.

I suggest you star it as all the updates will be posted there.